# Не создаётся раздел реестра

Tags: c#, реестр

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey reg;
reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("EDIT");
```

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.IOException" в mscorlib.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Параметр задан неверно.
>
> Необработанное исключение: System.IO.IOException: Параметр задан неверно.
>
> в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String
>   str)    в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String
>   subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object
>   registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)    в
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey,
>   RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)    в
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey)    в
>   TrasherForWindows10.Reg.CreatePartHKLM(String name_part) в
>   Z:\xxx\projectvisualstudio2016\TrasherForWindows10\TrasherForWindows10\Reg.cs:строка
>   41    в TrasherForWindows10.Program.Main(String[] args) в
>   Z:\xxx\projectvisualstudio2016\TrasherForWindows10\TrasherForWindows10\Program.cs:строка
>   15

Нормально создаются только ключи подраздела

```
reg = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\EDIT");\
```

Нужно сделать как здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлено

> System.IO.IOException не обработано   HResult=87   Message=Параметр задан неверно.
>
> Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>          в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object
>   registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
>          в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)
>          в Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey)
>          в TrasherForWindows10.Reg.CreatePartHKLM(String name_part) в Z:\xxx\projectvisualstudio2016\TrasherForWindows10\TrasherForWindows10\Reg.cs:строка
>   41
>          в TrasherForWindows10.Program.Main(String[] args) в Z:\xxx\projectvisualstudio2016\TrasherForWindows10\TrasherForWindows10\Program.cs:строка
>   15   InnerException:
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может прав не хватает, попробуйте из-под админа. Еще бы хорошо текст исключения посмотреть.

Comment: из-под админа не помогает

Comment: ну а 'Message' исключения что говорит?

Comment: Машина не в домене ? Домашний ПК ?

Comment: домашний.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем MSDN, ищем функцию [`RegistryKey.CreateSubKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad51f2dx.aspx#Anchor_1), проматываем к разделу «Exceptions», находим там наше `IOException`, и читаем условие, при котором оно возникает:

> The nesting level exceeds 510.
>
> -or-
>
> A system error occurred, such as deletion of the key, or an **attempt to create a key in the LocalMachine root**.

Смиритесь, создать таким образом свой подключ в HKLM не разрешено.